# Add NOAA layers to OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers, noaa

I'm trying to add a NOAA hosted layer to an OpenLayers map.  I've seen some examples of doing it with an older (pre 3) version of OpenLayers and of services no longer offered by NOAA.  Has anyone tried to present any of the current NOAA services (such as the NEXRAD [ https://nowcoast.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/nowcoast/radar_meteo_imagery_nexrad_time/MapServer/0 ] image) to a map with the current version of OpenLayers (5.2.0 in my case)?

Below is the code I was attempting to use, but it is definitely wrong as it ends up trying to retrieve the HTML instruction page instead of an image.

```
var source = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    attributions: ['NOAA'],
    url: 'https://nowcoast.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/nowcoast/radar_meteo_imagery_nexrad_time/MapServer/0',
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var layer = new ol.layer.Image({
    title: 'NOAA Radar',
    zIndex: 1,
    visible: true,
    source: source,
    opacity: 0.7
});

map.addLayer(layer);
```

Comment: url appears to be too long for a comment, will post as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url: 'https://nowcoast.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/nowcoast/radar_meteo_imagery_nexrad_time/MapServer/WMSServer',
params: {'LAYERS': '1'},
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks!  Out of curiosity, and so I can apply this for other services from that site, where did the "'LAYERS': '1'" params and the "WMSServer" extension on the URL come from?  Looking at the original URL I don't see where this is documented.

Comment: A google search for "noaa radar wms" found the GetCapabilities link (the WMS url plus "?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS").  That shows it has three layers with Name 1, 2, and 3.